# Dynamic input form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, input, partial

I am trying to add rows of input forms from a partial. Some of the fields in the partial have collection_select:

```
<td><%= label_tag :book_id, t("book") %></td>
<td><%= collection_select :books, "books[:id]", Book.all, :id, :name %></td>
```

The problem is when I dynamically add rows of this kind only the last one is passed to the controller in the params. I did not pass collection to the partial because it is dynamically added. I would appreciate it if you can help me out with this one.

Comment: How are you trying filter the inputs that you want to see?

Comment: What do you mean, "more of this kind"? Several lines of `collection_select :books`? Then the browser will see only the last one of them (because they will all have the same id, and ids are supposed to be unique)

Comment: Yes several lines of collection_select :books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the param name is being replaced by clones.
You can add a counter:

```
<% (1..10).each do |i| %>
  <td><%= collection_select :books, "books[#{i}][:id]", Book.all, :id, :name %></td>
<% end %>
```

Of course, this is just simple example. Its better to control this counter by JavaScript events.

Comment: Marcin, Thanks for the reply. What if I don't know how many inputs there will be?

Comment: You can control it by JavaScript, e.g. using jQuery and rendering these collections as partials (sending using AJAX counter, getting as response partial, and then append it to the form)
Counter can be increased by clicking a button ("Add collection")

Comment: I am using javaScript to append the additional rows based on user requirement.

Comment: Well, if there is no limit nor validation, you can just add it all client-side. When rendering row for form, just change attribute `name` of newly created row (you can use jQuery method `.attr()` here, google it)

Comment: Hi, i'm back again. I'm trying to implement it using AJAX. How do I use the counter from the ajax call in the collection field?

Comment: As I said, you can render just a partial, which has only collection select with counter inside, then append whole response (the response will be a rendered HTML). Here is an example: https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq